# what is equivalent of =~ of ruby in php?

Tags: php, ruby, regex, preg-match

I am a Rubyist trying to implement some of my code in PHP and not able to get the equivalent PHP code for this particular def.Can anyone help me out.Thanks in advance.

```
def check_condition(str)
  str =~ SOME_REGEX
end
```

Comment: [`preg_match()`](http://php.net/preg-match) ?

Comment: preg_match($regex,$string);

Comment: @CORRUPT is it not bitwise NOT operator **?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan bitwise with `SOME_REGEX` ?

Comment: bitwise is `&` in ruby and `%` in php

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In PHP it looks like:

```
function check_condition($str) {
    return preg_match(SOME_REGEX, $str);
}
```

Unfortunately there is no regex-match operator in PHP unlike some other languages. You'll have to call a function. Follow the manual of [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) and the manual page about the so called [*perl compatible regular expresssions*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php) (preg) in general.

---

Something additional. After reading the manual page of preg_match you know that the method returns an integer, the number of matches found. As the method returns after the first match this can be only `0` or `1`. As of the loose typing system of PHP this would be good for using it in loose comparisons like:

```
if(check_condition($str)) { ....
if(check_condition($str) == true)  { ...
```

But it would not work in a strict comparison:

```
if(check_condition($str) === true) { ...
```

Therefore it would be a good idea to cast the return value of preg_match:

```
function check_condition($str) {
    return (boolean) preg_match(SOME_REGEX, $str);
}
```

---

*Update*

I have thought a little bit about my last suggestion and I see a problem with this. `preg_match()` will return an integer if all is working fine but boolean `FALSE` if an error occurs. For example because of a syntax error in the regex pattern. Therefore you will be not aware of errors if you are just casting to `boolean`. I would use `exceptions` to show that an error was happening:

```
function check_condition($str) {
    $ret = preg_match(SOME_REGEX, $str);
    if($ret === FALSE) {
        $error = error_get_last();
        throw new Exception($error['message']);
    }

    return (boolean) $ret;
}
```

Comment: thanks @hek2mgl this has helped me a lot to understand regex implementation in php.I am able to go well with this now :)

Comment: nice to helped you. Maybe they will once implement the `=~` operator. +1 for ruby ;) check my update.

Comment: yeah hope they will soon. :)

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
if (preg_match('/regex/', $string) {
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Could as well just do: `return preg_match('/regex/', $string)`.

Answer (score 5):

Isn't it [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)?

```
function check_condition($str) {
    return preg_match(SOME_REGEX,$str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an equivalent.

`preg_match` returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or FALSE if an error occurred.

`=~`however returns the position where the match starts, or nil if there is no match. Since nil is false and all numbers including zero are true, boolean operations are possible.

```
puts "abcdef" =~ /def/ #=> 3 # don't know how to get this from a RegExp in PHP
puts "Matches" if "abcdef"=~ /def/ #=> Matches
```